# dwa_local_planner penalize negative x velocities

Tags: ros, navigation, dwa-local-planner, move-base, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am using [dwa_local_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/dwa_local_planner) as my local planner and there is a parameter `penalize_negative_x` in the yaml file. In my case, it does not seem to have any effect, if I give my `min_vel_x: -0.2`, it prefers to go in the reverse direction for long duration although `penalize_negative_x : true` whereas it should just turn in place and go forward. Also, I was not able to find `penalize_negative_x` parameter anywhere in the source code of `dwa_local_planner` which makes me think if its really being used or not?

Any help will be appreciated. Let me know if you need more information from me.

Thanks in advance.
Naman Kumar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221925/dwa_local_planner-penalize-negative-x-velocities/) by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1464 on 2015-12-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) on 2016-02-10**:
Did you find a solution for this? I want to my robot's preferring forward motion too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`penalize_negative_x` seems to be obsolete. Check [this commit](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/commit/55d9a47b266963874bc6bb71b535c268fe3b46ed).

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robocop87](https://answers.ros.org/users/5183/robocop87/) on 2016-01-21**:
Can we edit the dwa_local_planner wiki to reflect these changes? It still says this is an option.